# How to Copy Value from one Input Field to Another Using JS

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have two inputs fields:

```
<input type="text" id="one" name="one" />
<input type="text" id="two" name="two" />
```

I want a function to copy the text of the first input automatically when we click on the second input without using Jquery

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A basic way of doing this:

```html
<input type="text" id="one" name="one">
<input type="text" id="two" name="two" onfocus="this.value = document.getElementById('one').value">
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if the user clicks on the `<input>` element, add an event listener to it.
Then, get the value of the first text field using the `value` property.

Here is your code:

```js
document.getElementById('two').addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.value = document.getElementById('one').value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="one" name="one" />
<input type="text" id="two" name="two" />
```

Here is a living demo: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/XWmezNV?editors=1010

Comment: Note, the demo shows that the second field doesn't update until it itself is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

here is the example to do this.

```js
var one = document.getElementById("one");
var two = document.getElementById("two");
function myFunction(){
two.value = one.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="one" name="one" />
<input type="text" id="two" name="two" onfocus="myFunction()" />
```